# Is it possible to use one sql query to iterate through hierarchical table till NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, hierarchical-data

For example i have table that looks like this:

```
| ID (This is primary key) | parent (this refers to other rows in this table) |
|--------------------------|--------------------------------------------------|
| 1                        | NULL                                             |
| 2                        | 3                                                |
| 3                        | 1                                                |
```

Is it possible to have ONE mysql query which would return me all hierarchy of parents till it hits NULL?

For example if i would ask for row 2 parents, i want to get row 2, then row 3 and row 1. And if i would ask for row 3 parents, i want to get row 3 and row 1.

(By the way, I want my table to have multiple rows with NULL parents).

Is this possible, if yes how to do it?

Comment: No, not with that data representation.  You can do so with a stored procedure or alternative data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this easily until [MySQL 8.0 recursive queries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html).

I did a presentation [Recursive Query Throwdown in MySQL 8.0](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/recursive-query-throwdown) for the Percona Live conference in April 2017, showing how to do this.

You can also see:

- My older presentation [Models for Hierarchical Data](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data)
- My answer to [What is the most efficient/elegant way to parse a flat table into a tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficient-elegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree/192462#192462)
- My book [SQL Antipatterns Volume 1: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](https://pragprog.com/titles/bksap1/sql-antipatterns-volume-1/)

Comment: It seems that I'm dealing with mysql 5.7. Gonna take a look at Adjacency list then. Thanks

Comment: Oh, while Looking at your slides i saw Path Enumeration, which is good for breadcrumbs, which I intend to use this table for. Marking this as best answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get the hierarchy from a single query in mysql using the structure you have chosen to represent your tree. You could switch to oracle (have a google for "oracle connect by") or use a different structure for your data (adjacency list) or run an indeterminant number of queries.